# I have a cpp error on UNIX

Tags: bash

```
Hans Lao@Hans ~
$ cd /home/ddscat130527/src

Hans Lao@Hans /home/ddscat130527/src
$ make ddscat
cpp -P -traditional-cpp -Dsp ddprecision.f90 \
ddprecision_cpp.f90
make: cpp: Command not found
Makefile:508: recipe for target 'ddprecision.mod' failed
make: *** [ddprecision.mod] Error 127

Hans Lao@Hans /home/ddscat130527/src
$
```

I need to install cpp but don't know how.

Comment: Use Google please. The first search result has come up with the below link. http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-install-c-cpp-compiler-on-rhel/

Comment: Which Linux distribution (Debian, Fedora, RHEL, CentOS, Ubuntu, Mint, etc.) is this?

Comment: @Ramesh When I tried option 1 of the webpage you gave me, it saidHans Lao@Hans ~
$ system-config-packages &
[1] 7368

Hans Lao@Hans ~
$ -bash: system-config-packages: command not found

Comment: "UNIX" is not enough information to help you with.  I'm voting to close as unclear.  I'll retract the vote once you provide us with details of *which* UNIX you are using, and the specific version and/or flavor.  You need to install a build environment and a fortran compiler, but the instructions for doing so depend heavily on knowing what OS you are running.

Answer (score 3):

On `Centos` you try:

```
yum install cpp
```

On `Ubuntu` you try:

```
apt-get install cpp
```

Comment: Chances are if he's running make and doesn't have cpp, he also doesn't have gfortran either, so you might want to recommend he install some compilers or the distros equivalent of build essentials along with the fortran compiler.

Comment: @Christopher I installed cpp from the package of cygwin, now the only error is the ddprecision.mod. What does this mean?

Answer (score 1):

Try `whereis cpp` at your command prompt - and add the path to your shell's `$PATH`.  If you're using bash, you can do this by typing `export PATH=/path/to/cpp`.  You can see your current `$PATH` by typing `env` or `echo $PATH`.